# returing one value from the database using php

Tags: php, mysql

How do I fetch only one value from a database using PHP?
I tried searching almost everywhere but don't seem to find solution for these
e.g., for what I am trying to do is

```
"SELECT name FROM TABLE
WHERE UNIQUE_ID=Some unique ID"
```

Comment: What code are you using right now?

Comment: so what is the problem? You want to know how to write such a query? or you are asking for a php method to whom you send this query and get one value from it returned to you?

Comment: I want to know how to write a php query to get value from such a query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch one value from the table using this query :

`"SELECT name FROM TABLE WHERE UNIQUE_ID=Some unique ID limit 1"`

Notice the use of **limit 1** in the query. I hope it helps!!

Answer (score 5):

how about following php code:

```
$strSQL = "SELECT name FROM TABLE WHERE UNIQUE_ID=Some unique ID";
$result = mysql_query($strSQL) or die('SQL Error :: '.mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['name'];
```

I hope it give ur desired name.

Steps:
1.) Prepare SQL Statement.
2.) Query db and store the resultset in a variable
3.) fetch the first row of resultset in next variable
4.) print the desire column

Answer (score 3):

Here's the basic idea from start to finish:

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect("mysql.mysite.com", "username", "password");
mysql_select_db("database", $db);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM TABLE WHERE UNIQUE_ID=Some unique ID");
$data = mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo $data["name"];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql = "SELECT name FROM TABLE WHERE UNIQUE_ID=Some unique ID";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["name"]."<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```